# SQL - Trigger "not in"

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a time trigger in the dubbing database. I want to check that character can't be dubbed in the dubbing of the movie in which the character doesn't appear. Here's the PDM:

[image]

and CDM

[image]

I'm the begginer with SQL but I know that there should be some trigger in the table 'DUBBES'. I tried to make something like this, but i got a message that trigger is invalid:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER x_character
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON dubbes FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

  IF (  :NEW.CHAR_id_character NOT IN ( SELECT CHAR_id_CHARACTER
                                          FROM APPEARS
                                         WHERE APPEARS.MOV_id_movie = (SELECT dubbing.Mov_id_movie
                                                                         FROM DUBBING
                                                                        WHERE dubbing.id_dubbing = :NEW.dab_id_dubing)))
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Character is not in this movie.');
  END IF;

END;
/
```

I would really appreciate any help.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which dbms? (This looks like vendor specific syntax...)

Comment: It seems that is ORACLE's trigger syntax

Comment: ORACLE 10g, SQL developer

Comment: If the trigger compiles with a warning, use `show errors` to see the details.

Comment: Why not make your `dubbes.char_id` foreign key point to `appears` instead of `character? Triggers should only be used for referential integrity if you really can't enforce a rule with constraints; they have more overhead and are harder to debug and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your code should be like this:

```
create or replace trigger X_character BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON dubbes
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE  
  haveit number;
  idmovie number;
begin

  select dubbing.Mov_id_movie into idmovie from DUBBING where dubbing.id_dubbing = :new.dab_id_dubing;

  select count(*) into haveit from APPEARS
  where 
  APPEARS.MOV_id_movie = idmovie and
  APPEARS.CHAR_id_CHARACTER = :new.CHAR_id_character;

  IF( haveit = 0 ) then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Character is not in this movie.');
  END IF;


END;
/
```

Comment: Why are you doing two queries, rather then a single query with a join between `dubbing` and `appears`?

Answer (score 2):

From your diagram, you don't need a trigger for this. If you redefine your `FK_DUBBES_DUBBES3_CHARACTE` foreign key to refer to `APPEARS.CHAR_ID` instead of directly against `CHARACTER.ID_CHARACTER` then the requirement will be enforced for you, without the additional overhead of a trigger.

(As an aside, you might find it easier to have more consistent column names, and simpler key names...)

Answer (score 0):

Begin keyword is missing after DECLARE

Comment: Thanks, i tried, but the trigger is still invalid (or it compiled with warning).